# SNOWFLAKE JSON with keys and values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a json in snowflake like that:
`{"53CefwEQlSZyZmk4n9s24qGV3m":40,"rSwfCfEH01TrDCs9E0C3CL1fhi":107,"system":2}`

And I need to transform it in separated columns like that:

```
user                         number
53CefwEQlSZyZmk4n9s24qGV3m   40
system                       2
rSwfCfEH01TrDCs9E0C3CL1fhi   107
```

Can you help me please? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Flatten it out and treat it as key/value pairs:

```
with JSON as
(
    select parse_json('{"53CefwEQlSZyZmk4n9s24qGV3m":40,"rSwfCfEH01TrDCs9E0C3CL1fhi":107,"system":2}') as V
)

select   KEY as USER
        ,VALUE as NUMBER
from JSON, table(flatten(V));
```

| USER | NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 53CefwEQlSZyZmk4n9s24qGV3m | 40 |
| rSwfCfEH01TrDCs9E0C3CL1fhi | 107 |
| system | 2 |